# Submitting form without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax

I am retrieving Google's weather API XML and using PHP. I'm retrieving the weather for any searched city.

Now, this "app" is under a tab and whenever I submit the form it refreshes and I want to prevent this.

Is it possible? This will be implemented in a dashboard - thats the reason I want to prevent the refresh.

This is what I mean: http://www.screenr.com/30As

The entire code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZshpF/
Simply, copy paste the code in a php file and it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).  Since you mention jQuery in the tags, it has a [very handy function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for making the call to the server.  But making the call from the JavaScript is only half the story, you'll also need something on the server listening for that call.  It would essentially be another PHP script which acts as a page in and of itself, but would return data in the form of (most likely) JSON instead of HTML.  It's not meant to be human-readable, but rather to be a sort of web service for your JavaScript code to use.

You can find a simple example [here](http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/).

Comment: Not only the tags, but also the nickname! :) @jQuerybeast: Yes.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Don't think of it as the only way, think of it as the better way.  You _could_ have the AJAX request be made to the same server resource and pass it a query string parameter to differentiate what you need to return in the PHP code, but this is considered poor design.  It's a separate request and should generally be handled as a separate server resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [jQuery ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Comment: Avoid using plugins unless you absolutely have to, otherwise you end up with a bloated application.

Comment: It may be, but in this case, you can do a straight ajax call using jQuery. No need for a plugin.